# Why use more than one or a few files for a computer application?

Tags: php, architecture, dry

I started making my own php very small framework then learnt the (very) basics of the Symfony framework. A small symfony website involved over 11000 files in about 1000 directories. I have gone back to my own framework and increasingly resist creating new files.

I am committed to creating DRY, MVC code which means I really need one file for the application and one file for code which is shared by more than one application. Essentially I need n+1 files where n is the number of applications I have built. This does not include resources like image files. Am I missing something here (before I invest too much time in this approach)? What are the advantages of distributing the code over many files? Is one big file worse than many small files which add up to the same total amount of code?

Comment: "I am committed to creating DRY, MVC code which means I really need one file for the application and one file for code which is shared by more than one application" i dont thing you understand DRY or MVC, its not about file\line count

Comment: I realise DRY and MVC are not directly related to number of files. I guess my question is do they or other considerations place constraints on how many or how few files are required?

Comment: 10 composer packages vs 1m spaghetti line single file. Nuff said...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: separation of concerns.

Suppose you have two applications, one that shows weather information, and another one that shows stock updates. Seemingly, they have nothing to do with one another, so you put them in separate files. After all, you really don't want weather code in between your stock updates code.

Some of this code can be shared. You could put that code in a shared library. So far, so good.

But what happens if you find that some code from the weather application could actually be used for the stock updates? For example, code to execute a web service client request. You'd have to remove that code from the one weather file, and put it in the library. And that library would become very large as time progresses, with functions that new applications may not need.

If you keep everything in a single file, inevitably these will become unmaintainable balls of yarn, with duplicated code, and other such niceties. They will be difficult to unit test, and you'll forget what code sits where, and what it all does. You'll have duplicated code, and a bug fixed in one place, remains unsolved in another.

So that's why it's a best practice to organise functionality in a way that similar functions sit together, so that `webclient.php` deals with web service clients, instead of this being lost somewhere in `weather.php`.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Your code readability and maintainability. For that you should employ

- Separation of concerns,
- Low coupling,
- High cohesion

**The explanation**

To elaborate a little bit on SeverityOne's answer. Not everything goes with a separation of concerns principles, even though it is undeniably one of the most important things in modern day programming (heck, in programming at all).

You may write your code however you like. I know a guy who wrote his code however he liked. But if you work in a team or your code is expected to be maintained by someone else, then prepare for your name to become a synonym of "dumb duck" and "aye-ho". When I started maintaining the said guy's code after him, his name just became a synonym of "dumb duck" and "aye-ho". Reason? Unreadable code with no thought in it. Where a task could take an hour, it took six to finally understand what that dumb duck meant with his duck ducking aye-ho variables. Thank gods the dumb duck doesn't work with us anymore and we threw the "code" he produced away and started rewriting from scratch. See my emotions spilling out? That's because that dumb duck was thinking the way you are: "oh, why go for readability and maintainability when I can get a sandwhich from the company kitchen!"

So that your colleagues like to work with you, you need to think of a proper way to maintain your code. You think of **separation of concerns** - SeverityOne already explained the thing.

You also should maintain **low coupling**, i.e. the degree to which different classes are dependent on each other. The idea behind low coupling is that your classes (or modules) should be as independent as possible and in best should never "know" about each other.

And finally keep in mind **high cohesion**. Cohesion refers to the degree to which the elements of a class belong together. The idea behind it is that the related code should be close to each other and bind all related code together as close as possible.

**An example**

You are creating a blog. Just think of a typical blog example. Bad approach would be to create 2 methods to list your posts and to display one post, all in one file, run the queries in the same file, write html and css in the same file, whatever else comes in mind. Why is it bad? What if Bob or Alice need to add a new column to the database? In how many places do they have to edit the `SELECT` query? How much of HTML do they have to edit afterwards? Can you guess how many hours would that take? 5? 17? 42?

Good approach would be to separate each blog post to a specific entity, bound to an ORM (or whatever else, but my personal fav is Hibernate(Java) / Doctrine(PHP)). Then, if used with Symfony properly, you create 2 short methods to select and display the listing or blog post details. You maintain HTML/CSS in Twig. What happens when Bob or Alice needs to add a column to database? A migration file with a short `UPDATE` query, one line of code in your entity, couple lines of code in Twig. Fast, clean, **maintainable**. Time? Less than one hour.